# How to sync two comboBox? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

There are two combo boxes. I need that when changing text in the first it changes in the second. I used the following code but it does not work: С#

```
private void comboBox2_Clear()
{
  if(comboBox1.Text == "")
  {
    comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
    comboBox2.Text = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: **but it does not work** what isnot working?

Comment: Better to use Events ,I think the second combobox isn't getting notified when you change data in the first combobox

Comment: I changed the event to TextChanged, everything worked. Thanks!